# finding the probability from moment generating function

Tags: probability

The moment generating function of a poisson random variable X is given as $M_x(t)=e^{5e^t-5}$. Calculate $P(X \neq 5)$

I can only think of using mgf to do expected value.....

Comment: Can you compute P(X=5)?

Comment: so I just solve the normal poisson random variable 1-P(X=5)? i got confused with the moment generating function...

Comment: ok got it so the point of this question is to realize the lambda... thanks!

Comment: The MGF allows to compute the parameter, which one needs to know P(X=5).